# Why is multiple class inheritance a diamond issue and multiple interface inheritance not?

Tags: c#

Why is multiple class inheritance a diamond problem and multiple interface inheritance  not a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Because, in multiple class inheritance, you may inherit two conflicting implementations of the same signature.

```
class Base1 
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base1");
    }
}

class Base2 
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base2");
    }
}

class Drived : Base1, Base2
{
}
```

So, which implementation would `Drived` should derive?
The diamond problem is just specific case of the above.

Now, interfaces don't implement anything - so there cannot be any conflicting implementation, and in C#, you can give different implementations, for each interface, even if they have the same methods' signatures, with [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)